# Touch Screen Ubuntu 10.04LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, touchscreen

I'm trying to get a touch screen working with Ubuntu 10.04LTS (32bit) //*changed to 32 bit*
-it is a serial touchsceen, connected at /dev/ttyS0 ,i know that works because I get garbage in the terminal when I enable it.
-before the screen used a 3m driver (I believe) in XP.

My knowledge of Linux is passive so I generally pick up something when I need it.  To get this working I came accross a lot of tutorials (a lot outdated a bit), I'm still at a loss to get this work.

- I'm not sure where to put linux drivers (/usr/ or /dev/?) most tutorials kind of skip over that part.
- I have tried editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf unsuccessfully.  I'm not sure what the syntax for that is supposed to be.

Thank You

Comment: If you're going to downvote please leave a reason.

Comment: Any particular brand? Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` if there's no nameplate.

Comment: no brand is mentioned in the file,  although i discoved I had a typo in the xorg.conf.  The name on the back is 'TATUNG'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1508944&highlight=3m+touchscreen

Comment: awsome. I never did figure that out, i'll have to give it another go.  So many hours lost trying to figure out that touchscreen...

Comment: I've been trying this for quite a long time but I can't quite get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of poking around found [this](http://tuxmobil.org/tatung_ttab_b12d.html). The exact numbers and devices might be different, but it's probably a decent starting point.

Comment: Thanks, thats a lot more detailed than a few others I've found. I still don't know what to put under "Driver" or what options are available

Comment: The `wacom(4)` man page describes what options it takes. Most of the other drivers have similar man pages.